# Where is the code that handles copy and paste in X?

Tags: xorg

Suppose I wanted to extend the functionality of the copy / paste between different windows, which library / package is the source-code actually in?

Comment: What kind of functionality are you talking about, are you experiencing windows that fail to copy/paste, or do you wish to have a better clipboard manager such as Klipper http://userbase.kde.org/Klipper

Comment: I think it is inside of the running windows manager ?!

Answer (score 1):

In the application or toolkit generally.  http://www.x.org/wiki/CutAndPaste has links to more detailed info, but the whole scheme is a bit of a mess.